# Valid user ID cannot be parsed as fbid in fb:admins

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I want to specify moderators for page comments using FB comments plugin. According to [spec](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#setup-account) I'd set my fbid to `fb:admins`meta property, however moderation link did not appear. When I look at my page via FB Debugger it shows an error:

```
Object at URL 'https:XXX' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 
 '10152336557208977' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.
```

Note that 10152336557208977 is my fbid.

When I set `fb:app_id` instead of `fb:admins` everything works fine. But I would like to add comments admins via id.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FBDebugger here explains that given ID isn't a valid global user id (don't confuse with app scoped ids) that it can understand.

I think in order to get this working you will need to use your global user id, which you can obtain i.e. by using dev tools on facebook.com by Inspecting any Element that may contain your global id as part of id and/or data attribute on html tag.

The first thing came to my mind was 'id' attr on  tag with my mini image in top bar: [image: top bar]

It looks like id="profile_pic_header_123456789" where 123456789 is my global id.

With that ID - crawler should be able to make you an admin of your page.