# How to get facebook global User ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

Is there any reliable way for end users to know their Facebook User ID without getting under the hood ([dev tools, page source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31019725/229949) etc)?  Those IDs are needed to promote users to moderators in facebook comments plugin.

Comment: _“Those IDs are needed to promote users to moderators in facebook comments plugin”_ – if that’s not working with an app-scoped user id, you should report it as a bug.

Comment: Seems unclear if this should be a bug or not, but report it for me so I don't have to ^^ see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003002/valid-user-id-cannot-be-parsed-as-fbid-in-fbadmins?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

There is no allowed automated way to get the global User ID, because that would be scraping: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

You can only open the source and search for "USER_ID".

Comment: Actually I mean not automated but manual way. And something less hacky than opening the source :)

Comment: afaik there is no other way anymore, i´m afraid ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could build yourself a webpage, and extract the userID from their fb profile page. You postprocess this and return value for "userID" (Just ask users to visit your page and give their fb profile link).

Comment: that´s illegal. don´t do that.